# How Can I Get Access to Photos Taken on My Droid II with "camera" program - from a Linux System?

Tags: camera, motorola-droid-2

I used to use a program called "camera" to take pictures. I was able to see what had been taken, and save (or not) as I took them. And when I attached the phone to the USB port of my (linux) computer, I could find the pictures in the phone's memory card file system, which could be mounted.

The program "camera" appears to have auto-updated. I can still take pictures - but that seems to be all - I can't access them, either within the program or via the SD card. I didn't see anything relevant in the program's menu(s) - neither the one I get from the phone's menu button, nor the one I get, briefly on the right side of the screen, when I tap a small non-descript image on the upper left.

Perhaps I'm now supposed to access photos via some other app - on the phone at least? Any idea what it might be called? And how on earth am I supposed to get access to the underlying files?

The phone claims to be running Android 2.3.4

Comment: It sounds like the Camera app's default have been reset to save pictures to the phone's internal memory as opposed to SD Card. Are you able to mount your Droid 2's internal storage?

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer, once I figured out the general principle - touch random places on the screen, and this app. *sometimes* produces briefly visible icons that apparently the designers find cooler and easier to use than using the menu button on the phone, or even an always visible icon on the screen....

If I swipe vaguely near the lower left of the camera app's screen (upper right of the device's screen; these positions are always in landscape orientation, whereas my device [and I] prefer portait) I can make a small square image briefly appear; this image contains a thumbnail of the most recent picture I've taken. When tapped, I can see that picture.

- I can then side scroll to get to earlier pictures.
- If I again touch the lower left of the camera app's window - which *can* be reoriented back to portrait when in this state - I get a set of 3 icons + a date at the bottom of the window, and one at the upper left. The date appears to be the date the picture was taken.

If I click the first icon from the left, looking like 2 upward pointing diverging arrows, I get a menu:

- photo share
- amazon send to kindle
- bluetooth
- email
- gmail
- picasa
- print to retail
- text messaging

Then a label" downloaded apps"

- concur

I guess I can send the picture to any program I wish, provided it's on the cell phone. How amazingly useful.

The circled arrow - 2nd from the left - talks about a "quick upload" app. which requires me to set up a "default quick upload account" to use it. No clue where it would be uploaded, or what privacy might apply.

The downward pointing arrow - on the far right - offers me the following list

- more  (That turned out to be a header, unclickable)
- delete
- set as
- edit
- print
- picture info

The icon at the upper left that looked like a camera takes me back to picture taking mode

So,

(1) It is possible to see what pictures you have taken.

(2) It is probably possible to get access to the files from other computers, by mailing them to one's gmail account, then downloading the attachments - much more "convenient" than having access to the image files - NOT. (I say probably because I have not yet tried this. Perhaps it will turn out that there are more bugs here, or another layer of impenetrable user interface)

(3) The files themselves are not made available directly to the unfortunate user/owner of the device.